# Get edges of faces in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created several node groups which are selecting vertices/points, corners, faces based on a boolean field defined in another *Attribute domain*. Here are two examples to show what I mean:

**Vertices -> Edges** (either edges for which both ends are in `Vertices` or at least one):
[image]

**Edges -> Vertices** (either vertices where all connected edges are in `Edges` or at least one):
[image]

I was able to create several similar nodes. But I couldn't figure out how to do the same for the case Faces -> Edges. What seems to work is this (although it doesn't feel totally right to me):

[image]

Note that this one requires to route through the *Geometry* (because of the *Capture Attribute* node), which is not the case for the other node groups.

What is possible is to get the *Corners* of *Faces* and then to get the *Vertices* for those *Corners* and then to get *Edges* where both ends are in this set of *Vertices*. But this way I get edges bridging two selected *Faces* but which do not really belong to any of the selected *Faces*.

This is what I have tried:

1. Faces -> Corners:
   [image]
2. Corners -> (Vertices ->) Edges
   [image]

And the effect is as described - instead of the edges shown on the left I get additional "bridging" edges (right):
[image]

**Edit:** To avoid confusion...

**Input:**

- Geometry
- Boolean field with attribute domain = faces

**Output:**

- Boolean field with attribute domain = edges, *true* only for edges belonging to faces where the input field is *true*

**Etc:**

- No geometry changes, i.e. no `Delete Geometry` or `Separate Geometry` (also not as helpers)
- (and of course nothing proximity-based)

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer but are you looking for the [Interpolate Domain node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/interpolate_domain.html)?

Comment: Ohhhh yes. Many thanks, I knew there must be a way to do this, but never came across this node. The name is [Evaluate Domain](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field/evaluate_on_domain.html) now and with this I really need just this one node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Forget everything below. @AlpineWorldCup pointed me to the correct solution, which is simply using the `Evaluate on Domain` node:

[image]

See: [enter link description here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field/evaluate_on_domain.html)

---

Ok, I think I found a solution myself. It suffers a little bit from the fact that there is still no possibility to iterate over things in loops in *Geometry Nodes*.

The limitation is that this might fail if an end of an *Edge* (*Vertex*) belongs to more than 4 *Corners* belonging to **selected** *Faces*. So in reality maybe it should "iterate" over more than 4 *Corners*.

It would all be much easier with a `Faces of Edge` node...

The idea goes like this:
To find out if an *Edge* is selected, given selected *Faces*:

- Find the top 4 *Corners* for one end of an *Edge*, prioritizing *Corners* belonging to **selected** *Faces*
- Find the top 4 *Corners* for the other end of that *Edge*, again prioritizing *Corners* belonging to **selected** *Faces*
- Check if any *Corner* in the first and the second group belongs to the very same *Face* (and if it's really a selected *Face*)

This replaces the node group shown under "2. Corners -> (Vertices ->) Edges" in my original post:

[image]

**Open questions:**

- What I don't know is if two calls to `Corners of Vertex` with the same inputs is guaranteed to return results in the very same ordering. Otherwise I have a problem here...
- I had the feeling that it might be possible to use results for the first end of an *Edge* (upper part) to create weights for the second end such that only one `Corners of Vertex` node is needed in the lower part. But I wasn't able to get this to work (without causing severe brain damage).

Comment: What do you dislike about using `Separate Geometry` node?

Comment: I just don't want to change the geometry here. Ok I at the end I probably want to, but before I want to do several steps of such field modifications before I actually use this to do something with the geometry. And even then this might be something else (not necessarily separate/delete geometry).